# AllJoyn - How to test the Control Panel service framework

Tags: android, alljoyn

I'm testing [AllJoyn's Control Panel service framework](https://www.alljoyn.org/about/core-services/control-panel) ([detailed description](https://allseenalliance.org/docs-and-downloads/documentation/getting-started-alljoyn-control-panel-service-framework-10-android)). There's an Android sample ([AllJoyn Control Panel Service Framework SDK](https://www.alljoyn.org/docs-and-downloads)) of a *controller* device but I can't find a sample of a *controlled* device (the controllee).

Is there a way for me to simulate a device that implements AllJoyn's Control Panel service interface as the controllee endpoint? An Android sample would make my day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is indeed no controlle sample in the android SDK, there is one in the C++ SDK

You'll find the documentation explaining how to develop a controllee in C++ here : 
https://allseenalliance.org/docs-and-downloads/documentation/alljoyn-control-panel-service-framework-10-usage-guide-linux-cpp

It seems you need to get the code from git and compile it yourself.

https://git.allseenalliance.org/cgit/services/controlpanel.git/tree/cpp/samples

It it actually quite logical as controllee will typically be device with no screen, or any user-interaction mechanism and thus will generally not be based on android but on a C / C++ firmware.

Answer (score 1):

Too late to answer! May be useful for others. Apart from information given in the accepted answer, we can also use AC sample as a Controlee which you can find it /services/base/sample_apps

Steps to run AC sample

- First build controlpanel, notification services
- scons BINDINGS=cpp WS=off ALLJOYN_DISTDIR=$AJ_ROOT/core/alljoyn/build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist WS=off BR=off
- exportLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$AJ_ROOT/core/alljoyn/build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/lib:$AJ_ROOT/services/base/sample_apps/build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/controlpanel/lib:$AJ_ROOT/services/base/sample_apps/build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/notification/lib:$AJ_ROOT/services/base/sample_apps/build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/services_common/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
- Finally run ./ACServerSample from /services/base/sample_apps/build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/sample_apps/bin

After you succussfully run the AC(controlee) device, then run Android Control panel sample. Make sure Android and sample apps are running in same network!